# Should I include  Facebook JavaScript SDK if I'm not using its functionality?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

I have built a couple of very basic applications to be used as custom tabs on my FaceBook page.  All that these tabs contain are some hyperlink images.

Is there any reason for me to load the Facebook JavaScript SDK if I'm not actually making use of any of its functionality?

Originally I was planning to do so just to associate the app's ID with the web page, but I see that everything appears to work just fine if I leave out the standard snippet of code, which I've pasted below.

What should my reasons be for excluding it if this is advised?

Adam

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
      oauth      : true,
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    // FB.Canvas.setSize();
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to load it if you're not using it. The JavaScript SDK allows to make client-side calls against the Facebook API and enables you to communicate with the actual facebook Site if your App is embedded into one (as a Canvas App or an AppTab). It's not required but provides additional functionality.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: The only addition I would make to the above is that if your custom tabs grow bigger than the standard FB frame allows, you'll need the code along with FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() to resize the iFrame to show the entire tab.

Comment: Would not loading the JavaScript SDK affect the "Insights" analytics for my custom page tab?  (That's really the only FB functionality I can think of that will be necessary for these extremely simple custom tabs.)  Thank you.

Comment: No, all data that is required for those "insights" is independed from what happens inside your app, it covers the Facebook part only. And btw: the JavaScript SDK's source is available at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-js-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of language you are using, it is good coding practice to not include code that is of no use. Getting into a bad habbit of doing so, can lead to performance issues at worst and maintenance issues when you start going through similar code that's not even used.